# Group by clause on values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have a table like this

```
col1    col2    col3   value
10       1        1     2.65
10       1        4     1.14
10       1        6     3.25
10       1        13    7.25
10       1        17    4.25
10       1        23    6.67
10       1        28    4.28
```

this is my table so i want output as below

```
col1  col2  col3  min(value)  max(value)  avg(value)
10     1     10     1.14        3.25         2.34
10     1     20     4.25        7.25         5.75
10     1     30     4.28        6.67         5.47
```

here i have to use group by clause to col3 values as 1-10 one group and 11-20 is one group and 21-30 is one group .

how can i get this query ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement in your select and grouping:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       CASE WHEN col3 < 10 THEN 10
            WHEN col3 > 10 AND col3 <= 20 THEN 20
            ELSE 30 
       END as col3,
       MIN(value),
       MAX(value),
       AVG(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1,
         col2,
         CASE WHEN col3 < 10 THEN 10
              WHEN col3 > 10 AND col3 <= 20 THEN 20
              ELSE 30 
         END
```